# Problema con consulta MySQL de 3 tablas

Tags: mysql

tengo un problema con la siguiente consulta

```
Select nombre, codigo_cita, nombre_sede, fecha_cita, hora_cita, 
       codigo_sedeFK, codigo_sede 
from pacientes as u 
JOIN citas as h 
on h.codigo_docenteFK = u.codigo_docente    //hasta acá todo bien
join sede as I 
ON I.codigo_sede = 1
```

Cuanto inserto el join sede, se supone que me debe devolver solo los datos donde la sede es = 1. Pero lo que me genera es que asigna de alguna manera le asigna a todas las citas que su sede es la 1 que equivale a Heredia...
Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por que el =1 debe ir en un where y no en la sentencia ON, por favor coloca la estructura de las 3 tablas

Comment: necesitas la relacion sede cita o sede paciente ejemplo: I.codigo_sede =  h.sede_cita where I.codigo_sede = 1

Comment: te podemos ayudar mejor si añades las 3 tablas para explicarte mejor el funcionamiento del doble Join que tratas de hacer y como debes aplicarlo

Comment: @Bryro Ese era el detalle que me faltaba, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es asi como funciona el `JOIN`, es mas justo alli mismo lo aplicas correctamente con el `ON`, podrias definir la relacion, algo como esto

```
SELECT  u.nombre, 
        u.codigo_cita, 
        u.nombre_sede, 
        u.fecha_cita, 
        u.hora_cita, 
        u.codigo_sedeFK, 
        I.codigo_sede 
FROM pacientes as u 
    JOIN citas as h  ON h.codigo_docenteFK = u.codigo_docente
    JOIN sede as I  ON I.codigo_sede = u.codigo_sedeFK
WHERE I.codigo_sede = 1
```

o si solo es filtrar por el id de la sede podrias no definirla si es que no listaras ningun campo de esa tabla

```
SELECT  u.nombre, 
        u.codigo_cita, 
        u.nombre_sede, 
        u.fecha_cita, 
        u.hora_cita, 
        u.codigo_sedeFK
FROM pacientes as u 
    JOIN citas as h  ON h.codigo_docenteFK = u.codigo_docente
WHERE u.codigo_sedeFK = 1
```

veras que filtro usando `codigo_sedeFK` porque solo filtras por el id, si fuera por algun otro campos de `sede` entonces si necesitas la relacion